# Java: Inheriting constructor to the subclass

Tags: java

As i knew, constructors,Instance Initialization block are NOT inherited to the subclass, but below code  inherits the super-class constructor, why it is calling?

**Expected output is** :
    from cons 2

**but its showing output like**:
   --IIB--
    from cons 1
    from cons 2

```
WHY? this output , *As i know "sub class should not inherit Constructor & IIB block"*
```

Please help me to make clear this concept.

```
public class X
{ 
    {
        System.out.println("--IIB--");
    }       

    X()
    {
        System.out.println("from cons 1");
    }
}   

class Y extends X
{
     Y()
     {
         System.out.print("from cons 2");
     }
}    


class Z 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Y ob=new Y(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "super();", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because this:

```
Y()
 {
     System.out.print("from cons 2");
 }
```

actually becomes

```
Y()
 {
     super();  //Call to X's constructor made here even if you don't call it
     System.out.print("from cons 2");
 }
```

The reason for this is that every `Y` is also an instance of `X`. It's necessary to call that parent constructor first, before any of the child constructor executes, to guaranteee that the parent attributes are ready to go.

**Edit**: here's the example to show that "super class constructors are not inheriated by the subclass":

```
class A {
    A(int intForA) { 
        //Do stuff...
    }
}

class B extends A {
    B() {
        this(3);  //Won't compile! A's constructor isn't inherited by B
    }
}
```

Instead, we do this:

```
class B extends A {
    B() {
        super(3);  //This compiles; we're calling A's constructor from B
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me one example which proves this statement `super class constructors are not inheriated by the subclass`

Comment: That makes sense now; added the requested example.

Answer (score 4):

"The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor."
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

"If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass."
 - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Comment: Can you show me one example which proves this statement `super class constructors are not inherited by the subclass`

Answer (score 2):

When you call the sub class constructor, it [internally calls the super class constructor using the `super()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)(Note section in the linked page at the last) and in your case, the super class for `Y` is `X`. Also, the instance blocks are copied in the constructor and thus are executed when any of the constructors of that class are called.

From the [init block docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

> Initializer blocks for instance variables look just like static initializer blocks, but without the static keyword:

```
{
    // whatever code is needed for initialization goes here
}
```

> The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor.

Thus the output in the below order.

`--IIB--` - From the instance block which gets placed inside the constructor of `X`.

`from cons 1` - when `super()` is called inside `Y()`

`from cons 2` - the SOP in `Y()`

Answer (score 1):

in you code `Y extends X` so ideally when you create `Y` class object it also create `X` class object. So its block gets execute first then constructor of `X`  and then constructor of `Y` .

Hence you are getting output like that.